# Converting ResNet50 Decoder code to ResNet18 Decoder

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, resnet, pre-trained-model

I'm trying to convert ResNet50 encoder to ResNet18 encoder for U-Net model from this repository https://github.com/kevinlu1211/pytorch-unet-resnet-50-encoder/blob/master/u_net_resnet_50_encoder.py. Its all new to me, I don't understand why changing the network like this does not work.

```
self.bridge = Bridge(512, 512)

up_blocks.append(UpBlockForUNetWithResNet50(512, 256))
up_blocks.append(UpBlockForUNetWithResNet50(256, 128))
up_blocks.append(UpBlockForUNetWithResNet50(128,64))
```

The error received is:
`Given groups=1, weight of size [128, 192, 3, 3], expected input[2, 256, 64, 64] to have 192 channels, but got 256 channels instead.`

Comment: what do you mean by converting `resnet50` to `resnet18`? Networks come with specific pretrained weights that are not naively transferable to other networks.

Comment: Decoder for pre-trained resnet50 to pre-trained resnet18

Comment: You want to connect the encoder of a pretrained resnet18 to decoder of pretrained resnet50?

Comment: I want to change the code to use pre-trained resnet18 instead of resnet50. Basically I want to build a decoder for pre-trained resnet18 as encoder to Unet.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain more coherently what you want to build. If I understand correctly, you want a pretrained resnet18 encoder. What layers do you want in the decoder? Should it be pretrained? if so - from what model?

Comment: I want to build a UNet with pre-trained resnet18 as an encoder and train the decoder myself. I need to build the decoder for resnet18. The repository is correct implementation but uses pre-trained ResNet50, I want to change that to use ResNet18 instead which means changing the decoder part in that repository. That is what I'm having trouble with.

Comment: If my understanding is correct, you replaced `torchvision.models.resnet.resnet50` with `torchvision.models.resnet.resnet18`, correct? Can you post the whole code that you modified?